# animationcancel event fired off in Chrome but not in Firefox - CSSAnimation's playState property returns Finished

Tags: javascript, rust, browser, css-animations, web-sys

I'm using the web_sys crate in Rust to manually set a div's animation property:

```
    let animation1 = format!("animation1 {}ms ease-in-out forwards", DURATION);

    // html_element is type web_sys::HtmlElement
    html_element.style().set_property("animation", &animation1).unwrap();
```

I also have a event listener for both the `animationend` and `animationcancel` events, specifically listening for "animation1" to end.

In Chrome the `animationcancel` event is logged intermittently, with the majority of animation1 instances firing off `animationend`.

However, this is inconsistent with the results from checking each `CSSAnimation`'s `playState` field manually:

```
let animations = document.get_animations();

for animation in animations {
    let animation = CssAnimation::from(animation);
    if animation.animation_name() == "animation1" {
        log!(animation.play_state());
    }
}
```

Where each `log!` statement inside this loop always prints "finished".

Furthermore, upon testing this in Firefox, the `animationcancel` event is never fired and the `animationend` is always fired.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, or whether this is a known issue?

```
Chrome Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (arm64).

Firefox 114.0.2 (64-bit).
```

Comment: You're likely to get a _lot_ more answers if you'll convert your question to JS, just suggesting.